# How do I correctly use productRepository?

Tags: product, magento-2.2.1

I am trying to get the SKU of a product, but I just can't find out how to correctly use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface. It works when i use the getList() method, but getById() leads to a timeout (see the following code):

```
class LiveItem extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item
{
    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ... more DI
        )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        ...
    }

    public function getQty()
    {
        //this works:
        foreach (($this->productRepository->getList(
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create()
        )->getItems()) as $item)
        {
            var_dump($item->getId()); //$item->getSku() works as well
        }

        //but this doesnt (4696 definitely exists according to the var_dump output above):
        print_r($this->productRepository->getById(4696));
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in finding out what's going on here?
I'm on Magento 2.2.1

Is there another way to get the product's SKU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**getById** return object of **\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface**.

Try this code:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
$product = $this->productRepository->getById(4696);
var_dump($product->getId());
```

Write me if you have any issues.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny, this works! I assume I can't var_dump the whole $product because it consumes to much memory - am I right?

Comment: Yes, of course. You are right :)